# excludeCat function reverses order of blog posts

Tags: query, pre-get-posts

I'm using the code below to remove category #5377 from the query on the home page. However, this code is also reversing the order of blog posts for some reason. How can I alter this code to *only* remove category #5377 and keep the same order of posts?

```
function excludeCat($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $query->set('cat', '-5377');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

Edit 1: Full `index.php` code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php if (dt_is_sidebar_active('homepage_ad')) : ?>
        <div id="homepage-ad" class="widget-area">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar('homepage_ad'); ?>
        </div><!-- #homepage-ad .widget-area -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!--BEGIN #content -->
    <div id="content">

        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="home-sidebar" class="widget-area">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div><!-- #home-sidebar .widget-area -->
        </div><!-- #sidebar -->

        <!--BEGIN #masonry -->  
        <div id="masonry">

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <!--BEGIN .item --> 
            <div class="item normal" data-order='1'>

                <!--BEGIN .hentry -->
                <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <!--BEGIN .featured-image -->
                    <div class="featured-image">
                        <div class="da-hover">
                            <span class="da-wrap">
                                <span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                <?php dt_overlay_icon(); ?>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php dt_image(300, ''); ?></a>
                    <!--END .featured-image -->
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <span class="meta-category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></span>

                    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                    <!--BEGIN .post-content -->
                    <div class="post-content">

                        <?php $format = get_post_format(); ?>
                        <?php if ($format == "image" || $format == "gallery" || $format == "video") : ?>
                        <span class="icon"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icon-<?php echo $format; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $format; ?>" /></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php dt_excerpt(20); ?>

                    <!--END .post-content -->
                    </div>

                    <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Read More', 'engine'); ?></a>

                    <!--BEGIN .post-footer -->
                    <div class="post-footer">

                        <span class="meta-published"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' '.  __('ago', 'engine'); ?></span>

                        <span class="meta-comments"><?php comments_number(__('No Comments', 'engine'), __('1 Comment', 'engine'), __('% Comments', 'engine')); ?></span>

                    </div>
                    <!--END .post-footer -->

                <!--END .hentry-->  
                </div>

            <!--END .item -->   
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

            <?php get_template_part('includes/index-loadmore'); ?>

        <!--END #masonry -->
        </div>

        <div id="masonry-new"></div>

        <!--BEGIN .post-navigation -->
        <div class="post-navigation clearfix">
            <?php dt_pagination(); ?>
        <!--END .post-navigation -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Edit 2: Added `<?php global $wp_query; var_dump($wp_query->query_vars); ?>` just before `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` in the code above and got this:

```
array(61) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["m"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["p"]=>
  int(0)
  ["post_parent"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["subpost"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["subpost_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["attachment"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["attachment_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["static"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pagename"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["page_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["second"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["minute"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["hour"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["day"]=>
  int(0)
  ["monthnum"]=>
  int(0)
  ["year"]=>
  int(0)
  ["w"]=>
  int(0)
  ["category_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tag"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["cat"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tag_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["author"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["author_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["feed"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["tb"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["paged"]=>
  int(0)
  ["comments_popup"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["meta_key"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["meta_value"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["preview"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["s"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sentence"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["fields"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["menu_order"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["category__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["category__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["category__and"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag__and"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag_slug__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tag_slug__and"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post_parent__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["post_parent__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["author__in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["author__not_in"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["suppress_filters"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["cache_results"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["update_post_term_cache"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["update_post_meta_cache"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["posts_per_page"]=>
  int(6)
  ["nopaging"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["comments_per_page"]=>
  string(2) "50"
  ["no_found_rows"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["order"]=>
  string(4) "DESC"
}
```

Comment: that code shouldn't affect order, something else is altering order.

Comment: @Milo But when I take out the code, the order changes back to the default DESC.

Comment: you've got something else happening, this is not normal behavior. the fact that setting the order does nothing suggests there's something else wrong. inspect the query in the template and compare the SQL being sent to the database- add `var_dump($wp_query);` and have a look. also- `$query->is_home` should be `$query->is_home()`, and you should also only apply it to the main query as Brad's answer shows.

Comment: @Milo I added `var_dump($wp_query);` and it outputted a bunch of code which I'm not sure what it means. I have included it in the edit above. I also included the code from my `index.php` page. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-5377' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Use ASC or DESC for order.

Add code to child themes functions file.

Tested and works.

Comment: I tried this but nothing changed. Also, since I want the posts to be in descending order, I changed `ASC` to `DESC` but the posts still remain unchanged.

Comment: Where did you paste the code?

Comment: In the `functions.php` file.

Comment: Try the code now as i changed it.

Comment: Hey thanks, Brad, but unfortunately nothing has changed as far as the order of the posts.

Comment: Tested and works. Deactivate all plugins. Any code using the same function?